# When I set mapCenterRegion, how do I know if the region did actually change or not?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I am setting up an animation that should be called when:

1. User reload the map
2. User change the map region
3. theMapView didAppear is called.

To handle 1 and 3 I have:

```
[self.theMapView setCenterCoordinate:[BGMDCachedProperties singleton].mapCenterLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Now, I can call "doanimation" right after that.

The problem is if [self.theMapView setCenterCoordinate:[BGMDCachedProperties singleton].mapCenterLocation.coordinate animated:YES]; change the region then doanimation will already have been called. Calling doanimation again will make it called twice.

I want doanimation to be called once, not twice in quick succession.